# iOS - change one pixel of a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, pixel

In my app I need to change the color of one pixel(of a view) to black, I need to do this in the `(void)touchesMoved:withEvent:` of a custom gester recognizer, which will be applied on the view. (I am making a pen like thing).

My question is what is the simplest draw a line behind the gester recognizer, the line would stay after the gester recognizer is moved/

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You have told us what you want to do. What is your actual question?

Comment: Will this single pixel be moving with the location of the recognizer, or it will leave behind a line of black as though like an actual pen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing in a view is done in `drawRect`:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF

You'll need to set an instance variable or property in touchesMoved to the point that you need to paint then call [self setNeedsDisplay] and drawRect will get invoked.  In drawRect you will draw a one pixel rectangle.

Something like this, modify to suit your needs:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
    [super drawRect:rect];  
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(self.cachedPoint.x, self.cachedPoint.y, 1, 1);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```